# C# convert byte array to int always same number

Tags: c#, byte

I have a method that turns a byte array into an integer

```
public int Encode(string input)
{
    var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input.ToLowerInvariant());
    return BitConverter.ToInt64(bytes,0);
}
```

Why is this integer not different for any input string?

For example

`input = "http://www.google.com => 31525695615402088`

and

`input = "http://www.microsoft.com => 31525695615402088`

Comment: because the first 8 bytes are the same?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because 64 bits is 8 bytes, and so `ToInt64` consumes only the first 8 bytes of the input array. What are the first eight bytes of the strings you've used?

And, as alexm notes, `Encoding.Unicode` specifies UTF-16, in which each character is actually two bytes ([usually](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#Code_points_U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF)), so only the first 4 characters count.

Comment: Also it is worth to mention that an unicode char takes two bytes.

Comment: It's also worth noting that the first four characters are "http"!

Answer (score 3):

```
'h' == 0x68
't' == 0x74
'p' == 0x70
```

Little endian, two-byte characters, so "http" gives you an array that starts with :

```
{ 0x68, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x74, 0x00, 0x70, 0x00 ...
```

Interpret this as a little-endian 32-bit integer, and you get:

```
0x0070007400740068
```

Which, of course is equal to 31525695615402088

Answer (score 2):

An int64 is 8 bytes.  I'm sure you can figure it out from there.

Answer (score 2):

This occurs because a 64-bit integer uses 8-bytes of memory, and BitConverter will only convert using the first 8 bytes of the byte array you specified, starting from position 0. Each sample input you provided starts with the same 8 bytes.

For what it's worth, it's not possible to perform loss-less encoding of a string of variable length into an integer data type with a size of 4 - 8 bytes. You may be looking for a **hashing algorithm** that represents your data in a finite number of bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, ToInt64 uses 8 bytes - that's 4 unicode characters.

Answer (score 0):

Because `BitConverter.ToInt64` takes only the first 8 bytes of your byte array which are the same for your strings. Try input strings "google.com" and "yahoo.com".